How to recite Modeh Ani
I've seen the Minhag (look here) to recite Modeh Ani with ones hands clasped together by the chest, tilted slightly to the left and head bowed.
Where does this Minhag originated from and what is the reason behind it?

It's Minhag Chabad. See this question for sources.

@shmosel thank you for this. It doesn't really explain why the custom is like that, rather it just states that it is the custom.

The point was there are things we do because they're tradition, even if we don't know the reason.

I'm not familiar with the head tilt detail. Where did you get that from?

Rabbi Manis Friedman mentions it and I saw it in one of the Rayatz diarys iirc @shmosel. Moishe, I think it is very curious you are emulating the Rayatz with your question, but apparently you don't accept the same answer? :)

@RabbiKaii To be clear, I'm asking about the tilt to the left, not the bow.
